# Optimize filter + update join loops in PySpark dataframes

Tags: sql, apache-spark, optimization, pyspark, query-optimization

We have a PySpark dataframe that represents a school with 35 students and 3 classes, with each Row representing a student. Class #1 has 20 students, Class #2 has 10 students and Class #3 has 5 students.

We want to compare the three classes and thus we will assign an exam to a minimum of 4 students and a maximum of half the size of the class in each class. These students must be selected randomly.

[image: Visual description of task]

How can this task be executed as efficiently as possible? I share here the code that I have built so far.

```
students = students.withColumn("exam", sf.lit(None))
for class_ in students.select("classroom").distinct().collect():

    for group_ in ['TEST', 'NO_TEST']:
        subdf = students.filter(sf.col("classroom") == class_[0])

            if group_ == 'TEST':
                subdf_group = subdf.sample(False, 0.5).limit(4) \
                    .withColumn("exam", sf.lit("EXAM"))

             else:
                 subdf_group = subdf.filter(sf.isnull(sf.col("exam"))) \
                    .withColumn("exam", sf.lit("NO_EXAM"))

         students = self.update_df(students, subdf_group)


def update_df(self, df_, new_df_):
    """
    A left join that updates the values from the students df with the new
    values on exam column.
    """
    out_df = df_.alias('l') \
        .join(new_df_.select("student_id", "exam").alias('r'),
              on="student_id", how="left").select(
        "student_id",
        self.update_column("exam")
    )
    return out_df


def update_column(column_name: str, left: str ='l', right: str ='r'):
    """
    When joining two dfs with same column names, we keep the column values from
    the right dataframe when values on right are not null, else, we keep the
    values on the left column.
    """
    return sf.when(~sf.isnull(sf.col(f'{right}.{column_name}')),
                   sf.col(f'{right}.{column_name}')) \
        .otherwise(sf.col(f'{left}.{column_name}')).alias(column_name)
```

This is a toy example. In reality we have 135 classes and a total of 4 million rows in the dataframe, and the task is running poorly with the code that I have shared above.

Comment: Do not use `collect` to run a for loop. Your code will run in a single computer and wasted the fact that you have PySpark in place and probably a full load of cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you shared is very un-sparky in nature.
Best performance is when not using python loops and multiple shuffles. In the code shared the python loop creates a Spark plan with num of classes in the dataset X filters and joins (join = heavy shuffle operation) hence the poor performance.

Assuming you have a dataframe with two columns `["class", "student"]` here is how I would do this using **window functions**.
Spark will send each window function partition (in our case class) to a different executor so you will parallelize the sampling with no need to filter the big df each time.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, row_number, rand, count
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df \
.select(
    "*",
    row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('class').orderBy(rand(123))).alias('random_position'),
    count("*").over(Window.partitionBy('class')).alias('num_students_in_class'),
    ) \
.withColumn(
    "takes_test",
    (col("random_position") <= 4) &
     ((col("num_students_in_class") / 2) > col("random_position")))
```

Comment: Thank you very, very much for helping me. You don't know how helpful you've been. This worked like a charm.